# Inconsistent GetChartElement return data

Tags: excel, vba

Background:
Using Excel GetChartElement to determine what portion of chart user has clicked.
Then using that to determine next steps in code.
Issue is that one machine reports a GetChartElement ElementID (from .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2) that is different on one machine than on three anothers.  All machines have Office 365 installed and are current.
I have transferred the exact file to four machines and get three with right answer and one does not.  Suspect corruption somewhere as the one USED to give the right answer as well.

Question:
Does this GetChartElement function use any code outside of Office365 that could differ between machines?

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent investigation revealed the answer so I will answer myself.

Hardware setup is a laptop with a secondary screen, with desktop extended over both displays, and the spreadsheet ('XLS') in question above was on the secondary screen.

When the XLS was on secondary screen, the GetChartElementID responded with erratic results on parameters ElementID, Arg1 and Arg2.
Move the XLS to main screen, all ok.

Move XLS to other single screen machines, all ok.

Setup other machine with same second screen, extend desktop, and STILL all ok.

Conclusion, this is less likely to be Excel issue but perhaps Excel <> Driver issue.
(note the x and y parameters appeared to be ok in all tests)

Thanks